# Checking if a Python array only includes a set list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays

To check user input, I'm trying to see of the input only includes a list of numbers. The input is a 100x100 array with numbers -1,0 and 1. And now I'm trying with an if statement to check if this array only includes the above numbers.

```
if np.all(Array) == (-1,0,1):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I also tried:

```
if np.any(Array) == -1 and np.any(Array) == 0 and np.any(Array) == 1:

if np.all(Array) == -1 and 0 and 1:
```

But nothing worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to turn the `array` to `set`:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([[-1,0,-1],[1,1,1]])
if set(x.flatten())=={1,0,-1}:
    print "yes"
```

Or use `unique()` method to find the unique elements of an array.:

```
if set(np.unique(x))=={1,0,-1}:
    print "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.unique to get a sorted array of the unique elements in the array.

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,1],[0,1],[1,-1]]

def foo(a):
  lst = [-1,0,1]
  if isinstance(np.unique(a) == lst, bool) and not(np.unique(a) == lst):
    return False
  elif np.all(np.unique(a) == lst) == True:
    return True

print foo(a) ##prints True because the array 3x3 array 'a' only contains the elements -1,0,1
```

Note: comparing the 2 arrays returns False if all the elements are not equal and returns an array of 3 'True' elements if all the elements are true, therefore we need to use np.all to make sure all the 3 elements returned by the equality comparison are True